# In intervention/image, how can I change the color of the non-transparent part of a png file?

Tags: php, intervention

I want to change my image's color but for it retain transparency. I cannot use the `fill()` method because it has a regular sharp rule, and my image is irregular. So what should I do with intervention/image?

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do this with the colorize function in intervention.

```
$image = Image::make($path);
$color = '#abcdef';

$r = round((hexdec(substr($color, 1, 2)) * 200) / 255) - 100;
$g = round((hexdec(substr($color, 3, 2)) * 200) / 255) - 100;
$b = round((hexdec(substr($color, 5, 2)) * 200) / 255) - 100;

// Apply or remove color from a neutral #7F7F7F color image
$image->colorize($r,$g,$b);
```

I convert every component of the hex color to dec and then convert it to an scale from -100 to 100 to use it in the colorize function. this has to be done in a fully #7F image which is a totally neutral grey, for it to get the right color.

This is a really old question, but i hope this helps other people who get into the same issue.